# Azure Key Vault high volume KeyUnwrap operation when using table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

We are currently using a *CacheKeyResolver* together with a *TableEncryptionPolicy* to store encrypted data in Azure tables where some entities have an *EncryptProperty* attribute. This involves creating a symmetric key for each row of data in each table and sending that key to Azure Key Vault to get unwrapped every time we want to read out data from the tables.

What we are currently experiencing is that we have around 30 million operations/month costing us a lot of credit. This only to use our private key from the vault to unwrap unique symmetric keys used in table storage.

Is there a better and more performant way of doing this by loading the private key in memory or such that we don't need to use the **unwrap** operation for each row?